# writing an expression in qgis (2.14.0)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, expression

I have (qgis 2.14.0 Essen).

I wanted to write an expression using 'select features using an expression' but the page did not show the 'field' part from which I can click on 'load all unique value'.

Does anyone know what I can do?

---

Attached is the srceenshot.

[image]

Comment: What are the field names and the values which you want to use in this expression.  Can you screen shot the expression page with what you have tried.  Once we can see the fields, etc, we can help with the correct expression.

Comment: screenshot please

Comment: On the panel on the right-hand side in the middle, you can see a small dot. Click and drag that to the left, it should open an extra panel containing the available values.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work as expected for me, look for `Fields and Values` in the centre panel and the values will appear in the right hand panel. If you have made the left and centre panels too large you can lose the right panel against the margin.

[image]